# Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

quiero enviar una consulta de una base de datos mySQL como una petición vía POST, y desde express me manda el siguiente error cuando hago la petición:
Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake

```html
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '*******',
    database: '*******',
    user: '***********',
    password: '******',
});

function respuesta() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            con.query("SELECT texto FROM respuestas", function (err, result, fields) {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log(result);
            });
          });
    });

}
```

Utilizo node.js, express y  MySQL. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado, basta con eliminar la conexión continua (.connect) a la bbdd y ya funciona, en el método correspondiente.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo de la solución propuesta

Problema:

```
const selectBD = () => {
   

             con.connect(function(err) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                  //Select all customers and return the result object:
                  con.query("SELECT * FROM link limit 0,1", function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(result);

                  });

                });
           //con.destroy();
  
 }
```

Solución:

```
const selectBD = () => {
   

             con.query("SELECT * FROM link limit 0,1", function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(result);

                  });
           //con.destroy();
  
 }
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Las respuestas con tan solo código no ayudan a que los visitantes entiendan la solución. Léete [answer] para aprender las normas básicas para crear buenas respuestas, y de paso haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio, gracias.  En este caso esta respuesta ha llegado a revisión por ser de baja calidad y podria ser eliminada o [votada negativamente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/263200) por ser solo código.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar el modulo de mysql2 de npm, ya que este tiene un manejador de conexiones de manera que lo cierra automaticamente, ese error ocurre, por enviar multiples conexiones y no cerrarlas.